# Is it haram if a muslim intentionally ignores treatment for a fatal disease that is totally treatable if diagnosed early?

Tags: halal-haram, suicide

Suicide is haram in Islam. If a muslim were early diagnosed to have a fatal disease that could be cured if treatment starts immediately, is it haram for a muslim to embrace their circumstances, seeing the disease as their way of escaping this life?